# Pipe output to CSV or txt format with some text inbetween

Tags: powershell, pipe

```
server1\instance1,LOGPp,Hegg_Role_USR,SQL_USER,SELECT,Tables,HR.departments
server1\instance1,LOGPp,Herr_Role_USR,SQL_USER,DELETE,Tables,HR.departments
```

qns: I need to pipe the result into a CSV or a txt files in the format as below:

```
serverName        dbname Role           type      permission objectType Object
server1\instance1 LOGPp  Hegg_Role_USR  SQL_USER  SELECT   Tables HR.departments
server1\instance1 LOGPp  Herr_Role_USR  SQL_USER  DELETE   Tables HR.departments
```

Not sure how to pipe it using PowerShell...

Comment: Where do you get the output? Depending on the source, you could import it readily as CSV and export with `Export-CSV`. As to how, depends on the source reading.

Answer (score 1):

try Something like this:

```
import-csv C:\temp\yourfile.csv| Format-Table -AutoSize | out-file C:\temp\yourfile.csv
```

Answer (score 0):

If your source file is literal and missing headers, you've to insert them.

```
$CsvFile = "Q:\Test\2017-01\22\SO_41788212.csv"
import-csv $CsvFile -Header serverName,dbname,Role,type,permission,objectType,Object|
   Format-Table -AutoSize | out-file "$CsvFile.txt"
```

Output with underlined column names:

```
> Get-Content .\SO_41788212.csv.txt

serverName        dbname Role          type     permission objectType Object
----------        ------ ----          ----     ---------- ---------- ------
server1\instance1 LOGPp  Hegg_Role_USR SQL_USER SELECT     Tables     HR.departments
server1\instance1 LOGPp  Herr_Role_USR SQL_USER DELETE     Tables     HR.departments
```